# How can I get both splits to scroll left or right at the same time?

Tags: split, scrolling

I want to open up two different parts of a document in horizontal splits (using `:sp`) and scroll both of them left and right together. For vertical scrolling, you would use [`scrollbind`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html). However, I'm not sure what to use for horizontal scrolling.

I know the capability must be available because when I use `vimdiff`, it scrolls horizontally in both documents at the same time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To scroll two windows together in vim, need to run `:set scrollbind` in each of them. As you noted, by default, this only binds vertical scrolling. In the docs for scrollbind, it mentions:

```
The behavior of 'scrollbind' can be modified by the 'scrollopt' option.
```

`:help scrollopt` reveals that you want to say `:set scrollopt+=hor` to enable horizontal scrolling.

If you just want horizontal scrolling (i.e. disable vertical scrolling), then you will also want to say `:set scollopt-=ver` or explicitly set scrollopt via `set scrollopt=hor` or `:set scrollopt=hor,jump`.

Comment: Cannot fully decouple scrolling. After having :set scrollopt=  (equal nothing) still move commands like 'm (jump to mark "m") or gg are performed on both my two windows. It's ubuntu gvim after doing a :vertical split with no file specified

Comment: Apparently I solved the issue mentioned in the previous comment by setting :set nocursorbind in addition to :set scrollopt=  (nothing)

Comment: Not fully solved. Another option was left, :set nodiff. My vim was thinking that I was diffing two views of the same file. The nodiff option removed the all-dashes lines that vimdiff uses to sync both sides.