# How can I switch to filetype=txt when entering insert mode for Vim help files?

Tags: autocmd, help-system

When writing a Vim help file, it's often useful to set the `filetype` to `help`
to show syntax highlighting and such.
But I find this annoying to work with when editing the document due to the
"concealed" characters; my cursor behaves in "strange" ways and I often remove
the concealed characters by accident.

I now set the `filetype` to `text` before editing, and setting it back again to
`help` when I want to check if my changed are valid.

I would like to do this automatically. I know I can do:

```
autocmd InsertEnter *.txt setlocal filetype=txt
autocmd InsertLeave *.txt setlocal filetype=help
```

But how can I do this *only* for help files and not other `.txt` files?

Answer (score 8):

## Asked: Setting the filetype

The autocommands in the question are a good start, and with 2 extra pieces of
knowledge we can finish it:

- You can define autocommands everywhere. `autocmd` and `augroup` are "just"
  regular Vim commands, not special syntax or keywords. So defining an autocmd
  from *within an autocmd* is perfectly fine.
- You can define autocommands to be buffer-local (see: [`:help autocmd-buffer-local`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#E680)).

Armed with this information, the solution is fairly easy:

```
augroup help_start
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType help call SetHelpFiletype()
augroup end

fun! SetHelpFiletype()
    augroup help_insert
        autocmd!
        autocmd InsertEnter <buffer> setlocal filetype=txt
        autocmd InsertLeave <buffer> setlocal filetype=help
    augroup end
endfun
```

I used a function here since nesting multiple `augroup`s inline does seem to be
problematic (the first `augroup end` seems to end *both* groups; you can opt to
not use an `augroup` for the inner `autocmd`s, but this can lead to them being
executed multiple times after reloading the vimrc file).

You will need a modeline which sets the `filetype`. It's pretty much standard to
add a modeline to the end of Vim help files, so this is probably already
present:

```
vim:tw=78:ts=8:ft=help:norl
```

---

## Better: configuring concealed characters

There is another (probably better) way to solve this problem: by showing the
concealed characters in insert mode.

The ftplugin for help files does:

```
setlocal conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nc
```

`conceallevel=2` tells Vim to actual conceal characters which are marked as
such, but `concealcursor=nc` tells Vim to conceal the characters *only* in
normal and cmdline mode.

However, this still confusing:

1. The characters don't show up very clearly as they are still hidden due to the
   syntax highlighting:

   ```
   :highlight helpBar
   helpBar        xxx links to Ignore

   :highlight Ignore
   Ignore         xxx ctermfg=15 guifg=bg
   ```

   `15` is `white`, which is my terminal's background colour (this always
   matches your terminal's background colour).
2. Only the characters for the current line show up. This can be considered both
   a feature and a bug, but I don't like it.

We can fix this with:

1. Use `:highlight clear Ignore`. This will clear the syntax highlighting for
   the `Ignore` group.
2. Tell Vim to set `conceallevel` to `0` (always show all concealed characters)
   when entering insert mode.

Putting this together, we end up with:

```
augroup help_start
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType help call SetHelpFiletype()
augroup end

fun! SetHelpFiletype()
    augroup help_insert
        autocmd!
        autocmd InsertEnter <buffer> setlocal conceallevel=0 | highlight clear Ignore
        autocmd InsertLeave <buffer> setlocal conceallevel=2
    augroup end
endfun
```

This will show the formatting characters, *and* still shows the syntax
highlighting in insert mode. In normal mode, it will show the help file as the
user sees it when reading it.

This method is also also a bit faster than setting the filetype since Vim
doesn't have to source a bunch of filetype/syntax files.

## Preview split

(With thanks to @PeterRincker's comment).

`conceallevel` is a window local setting. This means you can easily use splits. One for editing with `set conceallevel=0` and the other window with the default `set conceallevel=2`.

This is especially useful in combination with [How can I get both splits to scroll left or right at the same time?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2266/51).

You can create a command to show a "preview split" like so:

```
command! HelpPreview setlocal scrollbind | split | setlocal conceallevel=0 | highlight clear Ignore
```

Comment: `'conceallevel'` is a window local setting. This means you can easily use splits. One for editing with `set conceallevel=0` and the other window with the default ( `set conceallevel=2`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
autocmd InsertEnter *.txt if &buftype == 'help' | setlocal filetype=txt | endif
autocmd InsertLeave *.txt if &buftype == 'help' | setlocal filetype=help | endif
```

Or:

```
autocmd InsertEnter *.txt if &filetype == 'help' | setlocal filetype=txt | endif
autocmd InsertLeave *.txt if &filetype == 'help' | setlocal filetype=help | endif
```